# ng-click function affecting all ng-repeat elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

A series of links `apple, orange, banana` are created using `ng-repeat`. Clicking on these links will cause that fruit's color to appear below the link.

**Problem:** However when any link is clicked, the colors for all the fruits are shown. How can we restrict the click event to only show the color of the fruit that is clicked?

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hut13fox/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="FruitCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="f in fruits">
        <a href="#" ng-click="toggleShow()">{{ f.title }}</a>
        <div ng-show="show">
            {{ f.color }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

FruitCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.fruits = [
        { title: 'apple', color: 'red' },
        { title: 'orange', color: 'orange' },
        { title: 'banana', color: 'yellow' }
        ];

    $scope.show = false
    $scope.toggleShow = toggleShow

    function toggleShow() {
        console.log('toggle')
        $scope.show = !$scope.show
    }
}
console.log('Hello')
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set the visibility in each element

```
<div ng-controller="FruitCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat='fruit in fruits'>
       <a href="#" ng-click='toggleShow(fruit)'>{{ fruit.title }}</a>
       <div ng-show='fruit.show'>
           {{ fruit.color }}
       </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And format your JS like

```
function toggleShow(fruit) {
    fruit.show = fruit.show
}
```

Your object will be something like:

```
   $scope.fruits = [
    { title: 'apple', color: 'red', show : true },
    { title: 'orange', color: 'orange', show : true },
    { title: 'banana', color: 'yellow', show : true }
    ];
```

This way you can control the defaults

Also, you don't necessarily need the toggle method, you can do it inline in the html tag:

```
<a href="#" ng-click='fruit.show = !fruit.show'>{{ fruit.title }}</a>
```

Comment: If `$scope.fruits` is populated from a database, like `$scope.fruits = $meteor.collection(Fruits,false)`, how will you add the `show` attribute to false for all elements in `$scope.fruits`?

Comment: If they don't exist, angular will create them for you at runtime

Comment: Angular will set them to `false`? Seems like Angular set it to a value that hides the display of the fruit's colors.

Comment: Then you can change `ng-show` to `ng-hide` and let them be visible by default

Answer (score 3):

I would do this which doesn't require you to modify your model:

```
<div ng-controller="FruitCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat='f in fruits'>
        <a href="#" ng-click='show=!show'>{{ f.title }}</a>
        <div ng-show='show'>
            {{ f.color }}
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason this works is because an ngRepeat will create a child scope with each iteration. By using the expression `show=!show`, it ensures that the expression is evaluated against the current iteration's child scope, and each child scope gets its own "show" scope property.

Comment: Thanks, I think you mean "child" scope though, not isolate scope

Answer (score 1):

Change your code something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="FruitCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="f in fruits">
        <a href="#" ng-click="toggleShow(f)">{{ f.title }}</a>
        <div ng-show="f.show">
            {{ f.color }}
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And your JS to

```
function toggleShow(f) {
    console.log('toggle')
    f.show = !f.show
}
```

Basically, you were previously using a common scope `show` for all items which was causing the problem. And now we are using each fruit items separately to toggle each item using `f.show` by maintaining a key `show` in your each fruit item.

**See a working code here:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

FruitCtrl = function($scope) {
  $scope.fruits = [{
    title: 'apple',
    color: 'red'
  }, {
    title: 'orange',
    color: 'orange'
  }, {
    title: 'banana',
    color: 'yellow'
  }];

  $scope.show = false
  $scope.toggleShow = toggleShow

  function toggleShow(f) {
    console.log('toggle')
    f.show = !f.show
  }
}

myApp.controller('FruitCtrl', FruitCtrl);

console.log('Hello')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="FruitCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat='f in fruits'>
      <a href="#" ng-click='toggleShow(f)'>{{ f.title }}</a>
      <div ng-show='f.show'>
        {{ f.color }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Missed to remove `$scope`.